# SerialSocketEvent not firing

Tags: java, arduino

I have copied this code:http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java to a java project, and i tried this:

```
void setup(){
Serial.begin(9600);
while(!Serial);
}

void loop(){
Serial.println("Test");
}
```

on my arduino UNO, with great results, but when i tried it on my esplora, the program did not even fire the event listener for the java project.

Answer (score 0):

An Esplora and leonardo (both use ATmega32u4) require you to wait until the cdc serial is ready. The Uno has a dedicated Atmega8/16u2 controlling the Serial/USB comms.

In your code, after your `Serial.begin()` call, add a loop to wait until ready:

```
Serial.begin(9600);

while (!Serial) {
  ; // wait for serial port to connect.
}
```

Cheers

Comment: it still could not find the com port

Comment: Ah, I assumed you were talking about the code on the esplora. Have a look in your device manager and see if your computer even detects it. It is likely you are missing drivers.

Comment: i updated the question to make it more understandeble. i also checked my drivers, and it correctly identified as an arduino esplora

Comment: Hey Chris! I just wanted to let you know that I have created a new question, because this one seemed unclear. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31689079/java-to-esplora-serial-port-communication-issue) is the new question.