# Java to Esplora Serial port communication issue

Tags: java, arduino, serial-port

I am attempting to communicate between an Arduino Esplora and a Java process using the RXTXComm library that comes bundled with the Arduino IDE.

I have started with the code [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Java). Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31601099/serialsocketevent-not-firing) I have modified my Arduino code to be

```c
void setup(){
    Serial.begin(9600);
    while(!Serial);
}
void loop(){
    Serial.println("Test");
}
```

Communication consistently works with an Arduino UNO. However, Communication with an Arduino Esplora often produces no output, and when it does work, it quickly terminates with the message `java.lang.IOException: underlying stream returned 0 bytes`. When I use the Arduino IDE Serial monitor, it returns the proper output from both an Arduino UNO and an Arduino Esplora.

How can I ensure consistent and uninterrupted communication between the Esplora and my Java process?

Comment: I do not have a leonardo or esplora to test, however you can get something like [HTerm](http://www.der-hammer.info/terminal/) (best serial monitor ever) and see if the computer is actually receiving the data you expect.

Comment: I updated the question with new information to make the question able to be better understood.

Comment: Can you wrap the particular section of code which produces the error with a try/catch block, then combined with a loop, your code could retry x amount of times before really crashing, or at least failing gracefully.